# How to fetch comment associated with post using Vue

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, vue.js

I am building a forum with Laravel, and as the title says I wanna fetch a comment left on a certain post from my database using Vue.js,and show them on my show page.

I am using the url below to show a certain post

```
Route::get('forums/{category_id}/{title}','ForumsController@show');
```

The code below does not work.Any help would be really appreciated.

ps.I am using Vue.resource.

forum controller

```
Route::get('forums','ForumsController@index');
Route::get('forums/create','ForumsController@create');
Route::post('forums', 'ForumsController@store');
Route::get('forums/{category_id}/{title}','ForumsController@show');
Route::get('forums/{category_id}','ForumsController@showByCategory');
Route::get('forums/{id}/{title}/edit','ForumsController@edit');
Route::patch('forums/{id}/{title}','ForumsController@update');
Route::delete('forums/destroy','ForumsController@destroy');
Route::post('forums/{category_id}/{title}', 'ForumsController@saveReply');

//API
Route::get('api/posts/{category_id}/{title}', function($category_id, $title){
    return App\Topic::with('comments')->where(compact('category_id','title'))->firstOrFail();
});
```

Vue

```
new Vue({


el: '#comment', 

methods: {

    fetchComment: function (category_id, title) {
        this.$http.get('/api/posts/' + category_id + '/' + title ,function (data) {
            this.$set('topics',data)
        })
    }


},





ready: function () {
    this.fetchComment()
}
```

})

show.blade.php

```
@extends('app')
@section('content')
    <div id="comment">
        <ul v-for="comment in posts">
            <li>@{{comment.reply}}</li>
        </ul>
    </div>
@stop
```

post table

```
public function up(){
Schema::create('posts', function (Blueprint $table) {
$table->increments('id');$table->integer('category_id')->unsigned();
$table->integer('user_id')->unsigned();
$table->string('title');
$table->text('body');
$table->timestamps();
});
```

comment table

```
public function up()
{
    Schema::create('comments', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->increments('id');
        $table->text('reply');
        $table->integer('user_id')->unsigned();


        $table->integer('topic_id')->unsigned();
        $table->foreign('topic_id')->refrenced('id')->on('topics')->onDelete('cascade');

        $table->timestamps();
```

method to show a certain post

```
public function show($category_id, $title)
{

   $topic = Topic::where(compact('category_id','title'))->firstOrFail();

   $comments = Comment::where('topic_id',$topic->id)->get();

    return view('forums.category', compact('topic','comments'));
}
```

---

Thanks Jeff for helping me out

I revised it like this

```
fetchComment: function (category_id, title) {
        this.$http.get('/api/topics/' + category_id + '/' + title ,function (data) {
            this.$set('topics',data)
        })
    }

ready: function () {
    this.fetchComment(category_id, title)
}
```

But I get this error message

```
http://my-sitename/api/topics/undefined/undefined 404 (Not Found)
```

I am a complete noob, so any help will be really appreciated

Answer (score 0):

Your function `fetchComment` takes 2 arguments, you aren't sending it any.

```
fetchComment: function (category_id, title)

ready: function () {
  this.fetchComment() //needs arguments
}
```