# How do I pass a route parameter to Vue.js from Laravel

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, vue.js

I have a route like this to fetch a post with the associated comment.

```
Route::get('/api/topics/{category_id}/{title}', function($category_id, $title){
    return App\Topic::with('comments')->where(compact('category_id','title'))->firstOrFail();
});
```

The thing is how can I pass a parameter variables to Vue.js?In this case "category_id" and "title",so Vue can fetch the post as well as the comments.

Below is my Vue instance which gives me this error:

```
main.js:11749Uncaught ReferenceError: category_id is not defined
```

Vue instance

```
new Vue({


el: '#comment',

methods: {

    fetchComment: function (category_id, title) {
        this.$http.get('/api/topics/' + category_id + '/' + title ,function (data) {
            this.$set('topics',data)
        })
    }


},
ready: function () {
    this.fetchComment(category_id, title)
}
});
```

method to show a certain post

```
public function show($category_id, $title)
{

$topic = Topic::where(compact('category_id','title'))->firstOrFail();

$comments = Comment::where('topic_id',$topic->id)->get();

return view('forums.category', compact('topic','comments'));
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

ForumsController.php

```php
public function show($category_id, $title) {
    $topic = Topic::where('category_id', $category_id)
        ->where('title', $title)
        ->firstOrFail();

    return view('forums.category')
        ->with('topic', $topic);
}
```

Javascript

```js
var category_id = '{{ $topic->cataegory_id }}';
var title       = '{{ $topic->title }}';

new Vue({
  el: '#comment',

  methods: {
    fetchComment: function(category_id, title) {
      this.$http.get('/api/topics/' + category_id + '/' + title, function(data) {
        this.$set('topics', data);
      })
    }


  },

  ready: function() {
    this.fetchComment(category_id, title);
  }
});
```

Comment: Trying to fetch the parameter from the database through the listed route in the post

Comment: look this `main.js:11749Uncaught ReferenceError: category_id is not defined, category_id not defined` and you use in `this.fetchComment(category_id, title)`, **title** not defeinded to

Comment: try to do declare category_id & title before you use in method, example `var category_id = put_here_the_souce_of_category_id`, and do for title to, can i see full code ?

Comment: does that mean the Vue instance is not able to fetch data from the api above?

Comment: for full code please take a look at this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36003342/how-to-fetch-comment-associated-with-post-using-vue

Comment: I have just pasted above

Comment: I wanna use AJAX to fetch the record.Thanks for taking your time and help me.appreciate it

Comment: yes it is AJAX, try change your vue code with my code.

Comment: tried that.and i got this /api/topics/%7B%7D/%7B%7D 404 (Not Found)

Comment: in show.blade.php try `{{ json_encode($topic) }}`, what your get ?

Comment: It gave me a post thanks!!please see my new comment below

Comment: please see my new comment

Comment: you must fetch topic include comments and relpy on your api route / api controller

Comment: this is the data passed to my view http://s23.postimg.org/pm8biwg7v/Screen_Shot_2016_03_16_at_4_29_49_PM.png I don't know the syntax to show the replies on the view

Comment: if you want get reply value, you must while comments before and get reply inside

Comment: like this `<li v-for="comment in topic.comments>@{{ comment.reply }}</li>`