# Vue Js - How to get slug from url?

Tags: vue.js, laravel-5.3, vuejs2, vue-router

let me explain with example on that I am working.My project is in laravel 5.*. I referred [first](https://laracasts.com/discuss/channels/vue/vuejs-get-url-param) and [second](https://forum-archive.vuejs.org/topic/758/how-do-i-pass-a-dynamic-page-id-to-http-get-url/2) links but no luck.

I have 2 files **brand_detail.blade.php** and **brand_detail.js**

when I open **http://localhost/gift_india/brand/baskin-robbins** url it's call **brand_detail.blade.php** file so on this url **baskin-robbins** is my slug. so I want to pass **baskin-robbins** to vue js and want to get data for this brand item.

**brand_detail.blade.php file**

```
<div id="container_detail">
<brand-detail></brand-detail>
</div>

<template id="brand-detail-template">

@{{detail}}

</template>
```

**brand_detail.js file**

```
Vue.component('brand-detail', {

template: '#brand-detail-template',

data: function(){

    return {

        detail: []

    }

},

created: function(){
    var slug = this.$route.params.slug; // here I'm getting error that Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'params' of undefined
    console.log(slug);



    axios.get('brand_detail/:slug')
        .then(function (response) {
            console.log(response.data);

        })
        .catch(function (error) {
            console.log(error.data);
        });
}
});

new Vue({

el: '#container_detail'

})
```

In my **blade_detail.blade.php** file I have include below js files.

```
<script src="https://unpkg.com/vue/dist/vue.js"></script>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/axios/dist/axios.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/vue-router/dist/vue-router.js"></script>
```

---

**UPDATE**

I'm using laravel 5.3 so route is defined in routes/web.php file and my routes is like below.

when I click on any brand from brand list page then below route is use :
for ex : I have 12 brands list page like **Baskin Robbins** , **United Colors of Benetton** , **Cafe Coffee Day** etc..

Now if I click on **Baskin Robbins** brand then it's called below route :

```
Route::get('/brand/{slug}', function () { 

return view('brand_detail');
});
```

when this brand_detail blade template open my url is like http://localhost/gift_india/brand/baskin-robbins so from this url I want to pass **baskin-robbins** to vue js and want to call next route for get all data for **baskin-robbins** brand.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As you are using [laravel router](https://laravel.com/docs/5.1/routing#parameters-optional-parameters), you can get slug using this variable `$slug`. You need to get this in your vue instance. Getting inspiration from this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36025924/1610034), you should be able to do something like following:

**brand_detail.js**

```
var slug = '{{ $slug }}';

Vue.component('brand-detail', {

  template: '#brand-detail-template',
  data: function(){
  ...
  ...
  //use slug variable
  ...
  ...
```

---

**If you were using vue-router**

You are getting the error as `this.$route` is undefined, you have not injected router in the vue instance.

Make sure to add your router object in the Vue initialisation, see this working [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/yyx990803/xgrjzsup/).

```
const routes = [
  { path: '/foo', component: Foo },
  { path: '/bar', component: Bar }
]

const router = new VueRouter({
  routes // short for routes: routes
})

// Create and mount the root instance.
// Make sure to inject the router with the router option to make the
// whole app router-aware.
const app = new Vue({
  router,  
  el: '#container_detail'
})
```

Comment: before asking question here I checked http://jsfiddle.net/yyx990803/xgrjzsup/ but I don't understand how to add that code with my project so can you give me example with my code ? my route would be  http://localhost/gift_india/brand_details/:slug .

Comment: @watson Where do you have routes defined, can you add that code?

Comment: I have update my question so you will get idea about my routes.

Comment: but how to pass **var slug = '{{ $slug }}';** from blade template to vue js file ? I don't have any clue.

Comment: [this](https://laracasts.com/discuss/channels/laravel/passing-data-from-laravel-blade-to-vuejs) might help.